# How to override getitem method with indexing based on numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to build a class based on numpy.ndarray which `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods provide data based on indexing like this `Point` class:

```
import numpy as np

class Point:
    def __init__(self, number=20):
        dt = np.dtype([("x",np.float64), ("y",np.float64), ("alive",np.bool)])
        self.points = np.zeros((int(number),1), dtype=dt)
        self.points["alive"] = True

#    def __getitem__(self, i):
#        mask = self.points["alive"] == True
#        print("get")
#        return self.points[mask].__getitem__(i)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        mask = self.points["alive"] == True
        print("get")
        return self.points[mask][i]

    def __setitem__(self, i, item):
        mask = self.points["alive"] == True
        print("set")
        self.points[mask][i] = item
```

And if I try:

```
p = Point()
print(p[0])
>>>>get
>>>>(0., 0., True)
print(p[0]["alive"])
>>>>get
>>>>True
p[0]["alive"] = False
>>>>get
print(p.points[0]["alive"])
>>>>[ True]
```

So the modification is not taken into account, but I got no error, like I was modifying a copy. Also I am confused because I am not calling the `__setitem__` method but the `__getitem__` method. I tried another implementation using the `__getitem__` of the `ndarray` but there is the same problem.

What am I doing wrong and how to do this properly ?

Comment: There are two problems with what I wanted to do. First is that numpy array advance indexing (like points[mask]) return a copy of the array and not a view so you can not assign to it. Second one is that I used chained indexing (like [mask][i]) which means I call __getitem__  of the class than __getitem__ of numpy ndarray.
More precisions here [link](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/BasicIndexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it using pandas which allows to do this without chained indexing and get a view of the array instead of a copy:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Point:
    def __init__(self, number=20):
        d = {"x":np.zeros((int(number),)), "y":np.zeros((int(number),))}
        self.points = pd.DataFrame(d)
        self.alive = pd.Series(np.ones((int(number),),dtype=bool))

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.points.loc[self.alive,i]

    def __setitem__(self, i, item):
        self.points.loc[self.alive,i] = item
```

Which gives the correct behaviour:

```
p = Point(3)
print(p[:])

>>>>     x    y
>>>> 0  0.0  0.0
>>>> 1  0.0  0.0
>>>> 2  0.0  0.0

p.alive[0] = False
print(p[:])

>>>>     x    y
>>>> 1  0.0  0.0
>>>> 2  0.0  0.0

p["x"] = p["x"] + 5
print(p[:])

>>>>     x    y
>>>> 1  5.0  0.0
>>>> 2  5.0  0.0
```